# Symfony, Hidden Form Field

Tags: forms, symfony, field

i have problem with hiding my form fields. For example:

```
        ->add('new_password', 'repeated', array(

            'first_options' => array(
                'label' => 'Nowe hasło',
                'attr'  =>  array('style'=>'display:none;')),
            'second_options' => array(
                'label' => 'Powtórz nowe hasło',
                'attr'  =>  array('style'=>'display:none;')),
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false,
        ));
```

Field is not visible but label is visible. I want to have hidden field but label should be hidden to. I want to show it in Jquery after clicking on the button. Any ideas guys ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show it only when you click on a button why dont you wrap the newPassword widget in a div with display none?

But if you want to add attributes to the label you can use the option `label_attr` like this:

```
{{ form_row(form.name, {'label_attr ':{'class':'hidden'}}) }}
```

or

```
->add('new_password', 'repeated', array(

            'first_options' => array(
                'label' => 'Nowe hasło',
                'label_attr'  =>  array('style'=>'display:none;')),
            'second_options' => array(
                'label' => 'Powtórz nowe hasło',
                'label_attr'  =>  array('style'=>'display:none;')),
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false,
        ));
```

Answer (score 4):

First, this is not a `Hidden Field Type` but a repeated type you want to hide by passing a `style='display:none;'` attribute.

In general, if you don't want to display a given label, you may need to customize your form rendering.

**For example,**

```
{{ form_row(yourForm.new_password) }} {# in case you're using the form_row helper #}
```

should be replaced by

```
{{form_widget(yourForm.new_password) }}
```

Because `form_row(yourForm.yourField)` is in fact a shortcut for,

```
{{ form_errors(yourForm.yourField) }}
{{ form_label(yourForm.yourField) }}
{{ form_widget(yourForm.yourField) }}
```

**Also,**

Why do you need to hide a repeated password field this way?